# nth-child box-shadow

Tags: css, box-shadow

I have three `child`s, like this:

```
.U:nth-child(1), 
.U:nth-child(2), 
.U:nth-child(3)
```

All three have `box-shadow` effect.
Now, how can I remove `box-shadow` on `:nth-child(2)` when *Hover* on `:nth-child(1)`? I also want to remove `box-shadow` when *Hover* the rest.

Answer (score 2):

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.box {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 20px;
  background: tomato;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 4px #000;
}

.box:hover {
   box-shadow: none;
}

.box:nth-child(1):hover + .box:nth-child(2) {
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a rule like `.Container:hover .U` to remove the shadow from all children when you hover anywhere in the container, then add `.Container .U:hover` to add the shadow back on the hovered element only.

This is not quite what you asked for; there is no way for hovering on a later element to affect an earlier element.